# Laravel switch locale and keep the choice does not work on routes

Tags: php, laravel-5

My project is based on a multi-language interface and my URL's are the following:

```
www.mywebsite.com/en/login
www.mywebsite.com/fr/login
```

This is accomplished by using the `Route::group` along with the locales set in my config:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@index')->name('login');
});
```

And my full route:

```
Route::get('/', 'Frontend\HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/language/{locale}', 'Frontend\HomeController@language')->name('langswitcher');

Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'Frontend\HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@index')->name('login');
});
```

As you can see I have repeated the `Route::get('/')` as users might join through:

```
www.mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com/en
www.mywebsite.com/fr
```

Now, imagine that the user clicks in the France flag and therefore switches the website language, he is redirected to `www.mywebsite.com/fr` and from now on the login link is `www.mywebsite.com/fr/login`.

I found two problems after this logic:

1. If the user closes the page and later joins again, if he types `www.mywebsite.com` instead of showing the French version it's shown the English one.
2. By joining directly to `www.mywebsite.com` the login link is always `www.mywebsite.com/en/login`

**I solved the first issue** by storing the locale in a cookie and detecting the locale within the routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    // Language() is a class I created that returns and manages the $_COOKIE['locale']
    if (\App\Libraries\Language::has())
        App::setLocale(\App\Libraries\Language::get());

    // ....rest of the routes..
});
```

So now, whenever I type `www.mywebsite.com` the content/text that appears in that page is in FR or EN according to my cookie.

The second problem I have not yet figured it out, as using the code `App::setLocale(\App\Libraries\Language::get());` as no impact in the URL of the login.

No matter if the page shown is in FR or EN, the login link is always `www.mywebsite.com/en/login`.

Finally, the code I'm using to call the login page in my HTML:

```
<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Log In</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved the second issue**, I needed to add a condition in my routes.

Full route file:

```
if (in_array(Request::segment(1), Config::get('app.alt_langs'))) 
{
    App::setLocale(Request::segment(1));
    Config::set('app.locale_prefix', Request::segment(1));
}
else
{
    if (\App\Libraries\Language::has())
    {
        App::setLocale(\App\Libraries\Language::get());
        Config::set('app.locale_prefix', \App\Libraries\Language::get());
    }
}    

Route::get('/', 'Frontend\HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/language/{locale}', 'Frontend\HomeController@language')->name('langswitcher');

Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'Frontend\HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@index')->name('login');
});
```